# PHP / MySQLi: Login form isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, authentication, login-script

I wrote a PHP code with MySQL for a login form.
Now I heard it's better to use MySQLi - so I tried to rewrite the code. This is my working MySQL code:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = md5($_POST["password"]);

$query = "SELECT username, password FROM accounts WHERE username LIKE '$username' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);

if($row->password == $password)
    {
    echo "<h3>Hallo $username</h3>";
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

    echo "Login succesfully:";
    }
else
    {
    echo "Login not succesfully";
    }
```

To use MySQLi I tried to change it to the following:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = md5($_POST["password"]);

$query = "SELECT username, password FROM accounts WHERE username LIKE '$username' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);

if($row->password == $password)
    {
    echo "<h3>Hallo $username</h3>";
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;

    echo "Login succesfully:";
    }
else
    {
    echo "Login not succesfully";
    }
```

But unfortunately this does not work.

Comment: `"Does not work"` is not an error message - whats not working

Comment: Plenty of things could be causing this, you aren't doing any error checking on your queries.

Comment: @Steve I see. After the changes I just get a blank pages. But there are no syntax errors.

Comment: With `mysqli_` you have to specify the connection you are using when you run the query. Have you updated your DB connection to use mysqli?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins Yes I have a mysqli DB connection which is working.

Comment: You really shouldn't use MD5 password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: A blank page means you have error reporting off - change that and you will know where to start

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Then see @Pupil's answer, that's the one error I saw in your code.

Comment: You're not taking advantage of one of the key benefits of using an updated database library... query parameters.  Your code is *wide open* to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins You're right, his answer was the solution. Thank you guys for the help and Jay Blanchard for the information about the password.

Comment: I think you should follow a tutorial. This is a simple task and you need a lot more info about PHP/databases then this question will provide. I suggest you look up PDO as well and you need more focus on security.

Tutsplus has a good article on the difference: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass database connection string to [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) as first parameter and the SQL string as second parameter.

In your case, you are passing only one parameter.

That is why it is not working.

Corrected code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much.

Comment: @coder if this is working, please accept this answer as the solution to your question by clicking the tick on the left hand side.